# OGR_LINK_FIELD to filename in a Geospatial PDF

Tags: gdal, ogr, osgeo, file-path, geopdf

I'm using gdal_translate to create a Geospatial PDF. I'm trying to add file path to my feature when clicking on them by using:

```
-co OGR_LINK_FIELD=<column with path>
```

I am creating my PDF in the main folder and the files that I link to are in main/images/unique.jpg

In my VRT layer is a column with "Filepaths".

My code is:

```
gdal_translate -of PDF \main\input_background.tif \main\output.pdf -co OGR_DATASOURCE=\main\data\vrt_input.vrt -co OGR_LINK_FIELD=Filepaths -co TILED=YES
```

In the shapefile, used to create the VRT is column Filepaths filled with:

```
/images/unique.jpg
```

In the resulting PDF I see that file:// is added to the link, but when I click on it it open the browser, but doesn't show the image.

If I place the output PDF in the same folder as the images and set the filepath to

```
unique.jpg
```

it opens the image.

What can be wrong? 
Or is it not possible to use relative paths in this?

Comment: You write that the images are in main/files but the link is to main/images. Is that just a typo?

Comment: Thanks for you comment.
It was a mistake, i have changed it now.